# I want to exact match characters using regex in JS?

Tags: regex

I am learning regex.
I want to match something like this -
2 letters, 2 numbers, 4 letters, 10 numbers
All these need to be there and in above order too.
So far come with this regex

```
[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{10}
```

But I want to do exact match.
'XS42NLJK1234567890' should match but not this one 'XS42NLJK123456789015'
But its matching the 2nd string too.I want exact match.
Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Remove spaces from the character classes if you do not plan to match them. The main thing is you need anchors, `^` and `$`, around the pattern.

Comment: `[A-Z a-z]` means "any letter **or a space**". I don't think that's what you meant. This should just be: `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: Did the change. Thanks!